# Gramian matrix test

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Are there some test to know if a matrix $M$ is gramian ? $M$ is gramian if it exists a matrix *W* such $M=W^HW$. Also if it is possible to determine $W$.

Thanks

Comment: Every positive semi-definite matrix is a Gram matrix.. To determine W take the spectral decomposition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix it answers everything very neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gramian matrix is positive-definite. So it's possible to find square root. It will be symmetrical so this it is possible to write such decomposition for any positive definite matrix. The solution of $M=WW^{T}$ it is not unique, because starting from nonsymmetric matrix $A$ one can construct matrix $B=AA^T$ and then a symmetric solution of $B=WW^T$.

Comment: Positive semi-definite matrices have a unique square root.

Comment: It has unique symmetric square root. I meant, that matrix $W$ that is a solution of the equation $M=WW^{T}$  is not unique

Comment: Understood. Good to clarify.